# Can I watch two engines play each other on lichess?

Tags: online-chess

Is there a way for me to watch two chess engine to play each other on lichess? I want to know who will win under time-limit.

Comment: There is a list of lichess bots here https://lichess.org/player/bots You can watch their games, they will sometimes play other bots. Or you can even create your own bot and challenge one of these bots.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lichess bots playing against each other on lichess tv bots (https://lichess.org/tv/bot) or make your own bot and challenge online bots.

Comment: That link also sometimes include humans playing bots, but in https://lichess.org/games/bot there are more games and a higher chance of bot vs bot

Answer (score 2):

Besides the mentioned lichess bots, you can sometimes catch

- chess.com Computer chess championship at https://chess.com/ccc or  https://twitch.tv/computerchess with chat and background music
- TCEC matches with chat at https://twitch.tv/tcec_chess_tv